# Add _ to every file / Directory in folder

Tags: bash

Is there a script (bash) which adds an '_' at the beginning of every file and directory name?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for f in *
do
  mv "$f" _"$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | while read i; do mv "$i" "_$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directories are recursive, you need something ab it more complex:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Requires BASH and a find with -print0

#The source    
SRC=/tmp/writ

unset a i
#Read in the file names
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  # Get the file name, rip off the directory name
  fname=$(basename "$file")

  # Get the directory name, without the file name
  dname=$(dirname "$file")

  #I used 'cp' instead of 'mv' for testing reasons
  # Note how I put the underscore in.
  cp "$file" "${dname}/_${fname}"

  # This just finds files.  You can repeat the loop with
  # type -d for directories.
done < <(find $SRC -type f -print0)
```